# python input to another .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have found a script in python that converts .ttml subtitles in .srt

The way i should run it is:

```
python script.py inputsubtitle.ttml > outputsubtitle.srt
```

The problem i encountered is that i cannot bulk process many files at once and if a file has whitespace in the name it simply cuts it off like:

```
"sub title.ttml" becomes "sub.srt"
```

I have written some code to replace the whitespace:

```
filenames = os.listdir(newpathin)
for filename in filenames:
    os.rename(os.path.join(newpathin, filename), os.path.join(newpathout, filename.replace(' ', '_')))
```

The problem that i am encountering now is that i don't understand how to set the input/output to folders.

What should i search in the code? there's no "input" function in there.

Comment: Have you tried searching for `raw_input` or `input` keywords in your code ?

Comment: Look for sys.argv ;) You pass outside arguments with argv

Answer (score 0):

In your scripts, look for *argv* from sys module. This is how you pass arguments from outside. If you want to run that process in a loop, you could either modify the scripts that it takes in a folder with all its contents in a list and loop transform all contents, or use subproces.run to call the script for all files you wish to transform.

Update: sys.argv[0] is your script, sys.argv[1] is the input and sys.argv[2] output.

Given that sys.argv[1] is the input and sys.argv[2] is out put. I assume this flow:

```
import sys

in_file_name = sys.argv[1]
# do transformation and write them to back
tree = ET.parse(in_file_name)
root = tree.getroot()
# more code
out_file_name = sys.argv[2]
# write transformation to this file
```

Instead of passing a file, you could pass a folder path. You need to transform the transformation above to a function

```
import glob, os, sys

def transformer(in_file_name):
    # do transformation and write them to back
    tree = ET.parse(in_file_name)
    root = tree.getroot()
    # more code
    # instead of getting out_file_name from sys.argv[2] like
    #out_file_name = sys.argv[2]
    # we will generate from in_file_name 
     out_file_name = in_file_name.split('.')[0] +'.srt'

    # write transformation to this file

# let’s do that to all files in that folder
in_path_name = sys.argv[1]
os.chdir(in_path_name)
for file in glob.glob("*.ttml"):
    transformer(file)
```

To run it you only need python myscript.py folder_path

Note: wrote this purely from guessing what your script looks like ;)

Comment: the scripts uses:

'filename = sys.argv[1]

tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()'